# What is the difference between the data and dataSource in knockout-kendo grid widget?

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, knockout-kendo

So knockout-kendo has a option called data and knockout-kendo has a property called dataSource. What's the difference between the two and how do both interact with one another/change when I specify both a data and a datasource on the kendogrid of different values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of version 0.6.2, you can pass either the actual data, dataSource config, or an existing Kendo dataSource (kendo.data.DataSource) in for the `data` option.

In older versions, you would sometimes have to pass `null` for `data` and then pass in your existing dataSource in the  `dataSource` option.

So, at this point you should be fine with just using `data`.

Comment: So you are opposed to using both? Does data also give you all of the dataSource methods that kendoUI offers for dataSource

Comment: Ok- I just reviewed this a bit.  If you are explicitly passing an existing dataSource, then you can just use `data` like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/wXrqz/.  If you have some data items and also want to configure additional dataSource options then you can use both: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/2BxgS/